# Kubernetes POD versions

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

Does Kubernetes allow multiple versions of same micro service (not Kubernetes service) to be deployed in a Kubernetes cluster at any given point in time?

So, let's say I have a micro-service "MyCalculator". I create a POD to host this service.
this is v1 of the "MyCalculator".
I need that as new versions of the services are created, Kubernetes cluster allows these services to be deployed in the cluster, like so.

```
"MyCalculatorKubeService"/v1

"MyCalculatorKubeService"/v2

...

"MyCalculatorKubeService"/vn
```

The idea here is dynamically allow new versions, and allow access to these versions through a convention specified above. In the example above, I am thinking that the "MyCalculatorKubeService" is a kubernetes service.
The unused versions get decommissioned over a period of time through a manual trigger after reviewing which services are not getting any traffic for say x days.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario you will have to maintain a separate pod for each versions you want to keep alive. Use ingress to create separate virtual paths to each version of your application

```
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-v1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app/v1/
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-v2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app/v2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki as its extension of `@Charlie's` answer.

As it was mentioned in `@Charlie's` answer you can do it using [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

There are some [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers), however Kubernetes officially supports only two.

> Kubernetes as a project currently supports and maintains `GCE` and `nginx controllers`.

If you would like to use `Nginx Ingress` on `GKE` you need to add annotation to your `Ingress` manifest.

```
annotations: 
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

You could also use [Nginx Ingress Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) annotation.

When you are using `Ingress`, your services can be `NodePort` or `ClusterIP` types.

Depends on your needs you can specify which `path` should redirect to which `service` but you can also use `default backend` if you provide some random path like on example below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: hello-world
    servicePort: 60000
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1
        backend:
          serviceName: MyCalculatorKubeService/v1
          servicePort: 60000
      - path: /v2
        backend:
          serviceName: MyCalculatorKubeService/v2
          servicePort: 80
```

If you would provide path like `MyCalculatorKubeService/vasdsadsa` it would redirect to `default backend` which is `hello-world` service in this case. It might be used in some workarounds.